# Use checkbox to display side menu with only CSS

Tags: html, sass

I am trying to improve a website to be as accessible as possible to screen readers and people who want to disable JavaScript (not necessarily both at the same time) so I use a checkbox with a label to display/hide the side menu

Some of the `aria` attributes get changed by javascript depending on screen size and whether the menu is open or closed.

I'm just wondering if there is anything I can add for improved accessibility.

[Here](http://cocacolabevduluth.com/about) is the full page if you want to check it out in action:

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"/>
    <label id="hamburger" for="menu-checkbox" tabindex="0" title="menu" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" onclick="">
        Menu
        <div class="line line1"></div>
        <div class="line line2"></div>
        <div class="line line3"></div>
    </label>
    <ul role="menubar">
        <li class="nav-home"><a href="/" role="menuitem">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-about"><a href="/about" role="menuitem">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-careers"><a href="/careers" role="menuitem">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="nav-contact"><a href="/contact" role="menuitem">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
#menu {
    #hamburger {
        font-size: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;

        .line {
            width: 50px;
            height: 6px;
            background-color: #dc0000;
            margin-top: 8PX;
            transition: transform 0.4s;
            border-radius: 3px;

            &:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 8px;
            }
        }
    }

    #menu-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 0;
        text-align: right;
        touch-action: manipulation;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #dc0000;
            @media (max-width: 699px) {
                font-size: 28px;
            }

            &::after {
                content: "●";
            }

            &:last-child::after {
                content: "";
            }

            &.active {
                display: none;
            }

            a {
                margin: 0 0.5em;
                color: inherit;

                &:hover {
                    color: #f33;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
        #hamburger {
            display: block;
        }

        ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            transition: right 0.4s;

            li {
                color: #fff;
                display: block !important;
                font-size: 60px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                text-align: center;

                &::after {
                    content: "" !important;
                }

                &.active {
                    color: #dc0000;
                }
            }
        }

        #menu-checkbox:checked ~ #hamburger {
            .line1 {
                transform: rotate(-215deg) translate(13px, 1px) scale(0.5, 1);
            }

            .line2 {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }

            .line3 {
                transform: rotate(-145deg) translate(13px, -1px) scale(0.5, 1);
            }
        }

        #menu-checkbox:checked ~ ul {
            right: 0;
        }
    }
}
```